# Light-weight implementation of the TCP/IP protocol suite in NS-3

Tags: ns-3, lwip

I was looking for workable options available in NS-3 to use and modify light-weight implementation of the TCP/IP (LWIP) protocol suite. So far I have found network simulations cradle (https://www.nsnam.org/docs/models/html/tcp.html#network-simulation-cradle) installation as the only option but I can only see executable stacks for linux2.6.18 and linux2.6.26. There is no executable stack for lwip. I am also having a hard time finding any tutorial online on the usage of lwip in NS-3.

Is there any way to execute lwip stack in NS-3? If not, does anyone know of any other light-weight tcp variant (with limited functionality and small footprint) that can be simulated in NS-3?

Comment: What is your goal? What do you want to test/simulate? Network topology?